# C++/CLI wrapper for C++ class returning interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, c++-cli

I'm looking for a way to expose a C++ source code library to C# managed code in order to make code duplication as small as possible. The main problem is that the native code, which I need to adapt, uses many abstract classes as interfaces in parameters and return values.

For example:

```
class IXX
{
  virtual int DoIt() = 0;
}

class IFoo
{
  virtual int Foo(const IXX *) = 0;
}

class IBar
{
  virtual IFoo * Bar() = 0;
}

class A : IBar
{
  IFoo * Bar()
  {
    return new FooImpl();
  }
}
```

Almost all the samples I have found work with simple types (e.g. `int`, `char*` etc), but not with complex logic based on interfaces. As the possible solution, all the C++ code may be wrapped in C++/CLI, but it means a lot of code duplication.

What would be the good solution to expose this native code functionality to C#?

Comment: You need the wrapper; yes it's a lot of code duplication, but it's only painful if you write it by hand.  You can use SWiG to help generate the wrappers automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use SWIG because of licensing issues.

Comment: I'm curious why SWIG's license is a problem for you.  Its license shouldn't apply to the generated wrapper code, from the perspective of SWIG that is your data, not SWIG code.  It is like thinking that FSF owns copyright to a book you write because you wrote it inside their editor.

Comment: "When SWIG is used as it is distributed by the SWIG developers, its output is not governed by SWIG's license (including the GPL). SWIG's output contains code from three sources:

    code generated by SWIG, which is not governed by copyright;
    code copied from the SWIG library which is permissively licensed to be redistributed without restriction;
    code derived from the user's input, which may be governed by the license of the code supplied by the user."

Comment: ["So, while the input supplied to SWIG may affect the license of SWIG's output (e.g. if the input code is licensed under a copyleft or proprietary license), SWIG's license does not affect the license of the output. This is consistent with the FSF's FAQ entries on this subject (GPLOutput and WhatCaseIsOutputGPL), because the SWIG code copied into the output by SWIG is not GPL-licensed."](http://www.swig.org/legal.html)

Comment: And "SWIG is a code generator and the intention of the SWIG license is also to enable distribution of the output code under license terms of the user's choice/requirements."

Comment: The problem is that lawyers will review this license really long and sometimes they find something, which they cannot get through.

Comment: If your employer is that crazy about lawyers, they must be throwing fits about your participation on SO :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is probably to write managed wrapper classes in C++/CLI, and use those from C#. The unmanaged classes cannot be used in C#.

What you need to do is duplicate the public interface of all your classes, and have each managed object own the unmanaged object that it's wrapping. Have all the methods call to the unmanaged object to do their work, and any object results should be returned in wrappers. You should also handle any other conversions here as well, such as `std::string` vs. `System::String^`, managed arrays vs. pointer & length parameters, that type of thing.

```
public interface class IXX
{
  int DoIt();
}

public interface class IFoo
{
  int Foo(IXX^ ixx);
}

public interface class IBar
{
  IFoo^ Bar();
}

public ref class A : IBar
{
private:
  Unmanaged:A* unmanagedA;

public:
  A()
  {
    // Create the unmanaged object that we're wrapping.
    this->unmanagedA = new Unmanaged:A();
  }

  A(Unmanaged:A* unmanagedA)
  {
    // Use the passed-in unmanaged object.
    this->unmanagedA = unmanagedA;
  }

  // Clean up the unmanaged object on Dispose (~A) and Finalize (!A).
  ~A() { delete this->unmanagedA; }
  !A() { delete this->unmanagedA; }

  IFoo^ Bar()
  {
    // First, get the result from the unmanaged object.
    Unmanaged::FooImpl* unmanagedFoo = this->unmanagedA->Bar();
    // Return it wrapped in a managed wrapper.
    return gcnew FooImpl(unmanagedFoo);
  }
}

// (Note: I didn't verify the correctness of this code with a compiler.)
```

Comment: This is actually very close to my initial idea, but this is better